# Is ANOVA Best Way to Compare Groups of Students by Cum GPA?

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation

I have about 200 students who are split into 6 groups of roughly equal size, 30-ish.  They all have a cumulative gpa of between 2.00 and 4.3.  When the students matriculated, I tried to assign them to sections so that the sections would be of similar ability.  Now I want to see how well I did. Would ANOVA be the best way?
My reading suggests ANOVA would only tell me if the means of the groups were different.  But the groups might have similar means but different standard deviations; how best to determine if the distributions around the mean are different, that is whether the variances are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** I would make **boxplots** of the six groups, all in the same figure,
to get a preliminary view. Below are such boxplots for fake data (simulated in R): Classes 1-3
have average GPA 4.0 with SD .25; Classes 4-6 have average GPA 3.5 with
SD .30.

The differences in means and the differences in SDs both show fairly clearly.
If this analysis of class GPAs is just for your own personal curiosity, you might stop here.

```
x = c(rnorm(99, 4, .25), rnorm(99, 3.5, .3))
g = as.factor(rep(1:6, each=33))
boxplot(x ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=19, ylab="GPA", xlab="Class")
```

[image]

**Second,** in almost any textbook that gives serious treatment
to one-factor ANOVA you will find several tests to see if group variances
are equal. **Tests for equality of variance** are notoriously of low power
(not always finding real differences). You can try one of them to see what it finds.

For normal data, the Bartlett test is a popular choice. For the fake data generated above, the null hypothesis that all groups come from populations with one common variance is rejected, P-value 0.001. You could use two-sample tests (perhaps `var.test`) to
see which specific groups have different variances.

```
bartlett.test(x, g)

        Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  x and g
Bartlett's K-squared = 20.038, df = 5, p-value = 0.001229
```

**Finally,** even if variances are not equal, you can still test whether the groups
have equal means. You could use a **'Welch' one-way ANOVA test** that
uses approximation similar to those of the Welch 'separate-variances'
two-sample t test. With 30ish students in each group, this test should work well.
(I would probably use it in preference to a standard one-way ANOVA with
groups as large as 30, even if the Bartlett test detected no differences
among variances. But apparently there have not yet been enough simulation studies
on the performance of this test to say mine is a general accepted view.)

In R, the procedure `oneway.test` performs this test. It clearly finds
significant differences among groups:

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 33.377, num df = 5.000, denom df = 89.084, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

One of several ways to make paired comparisons to see where the significant
differences lie is the R procedure `pairwise`. Not surprisingly, it finds no
significant differences among groups 1-3, and none among groups 4-6, but
does find 1-3 to differ significantly from 4-6.

```
pairwise.t.test(x, g)

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  x and g 

  1       2       3       4 5
2 1       -       -       - -
3 1       1       -       - -
4 3.2e-09 3.4e-10 6.6e-10 - -
5 2.4e-10 2.4e-11 4.7e-11 1 -
6 2.6e-10 2.7e-11 5.1e-11 1 1

P value adjustment method: holm
```

*Note:* My main purpose has been to give you some clue what is available.
For technical details, you can google to find very many R documentation and help pages.